# Pushing object to array results in duplication

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to push an object, with values based upon an array, into another array. It seems to be going wrong on the second array.map function. Up until that point, arrValues contains an entry based on the first array.push.
By the time I make the second object and it's values, the arrValues array has the current object inside it, not the one I created

Very confused!

```js
let arrMap = [{
  "field_desc": "Building Name",
  "type": "string"
}]
let objFind = {
  values: [
    ["BUILDING1", "BUILDING2"],
    []
  ]
}


let arrValues = [];
let objValues = {};

objValues.row = 0;
objValues.values = arrMap.map(function(element, index, array) {
  let objFindExcel = objFind.values[0][0];
  element.field_value = objFindExcel;
  return element;
}, []);

arrValues.push(objValues);

objValues = {};

objValues.row = 1;
objValues.values = arrMap.map(function(element, index, array) {
  let objFindExcel = objFind.values[0][1];
  element.field_value = objFindExcel;
  return element;
}, []);

arrValues.push(objValues);
console.log(arrValues);
```

I am expecting this:

```js
[{
  "row": 0,
  "values": [{
    "field_desc": "Building Name",
    "type": "string",
    "field_value": "BUILDING1"
  }]
}, {
  "row": 1,
  "values": [{
    "field_desc": "Building Name",
    "type": "string",
    "field_value": "BUILDING2"
  }]
}]
```

But I am getting this:

```js
[{
  "row": 0,
  "values": [{
    "field_desc": "Building Name",
    "type": "string",
    "field_value": "BUILDING2"
  }]
}, {
  "row": 1,
  "values": [{
    "field_desc": "Building Name",
    "type": "string",
    "field_value": "BUILDING2"
  }]
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you modify the `field_value` property of the elements in the arrMap array, it affects all instances that reference the same object.

In order to fix the issue, you should create a new object for each entry in the arrMap array during the mapping process.

Refer the below code :

```js
let arrMap = [{
  "field_desc": "Building Name",
  "type": "string"
}];
let objFind = {
  values: [
    ["BUILDING1", "BUILDING2"],
    []
  ]
};

let arrValues = [];


function createObject(template, field_value) {
  return {
    field_desc: template.field_desc,
    type: template.type,
    field_value: field_value
  };
}


let objValues = {};
objValues.row = 0;
objValues.values = arrMap.map(function(element, index, array) {
  let objFindExcel = objFind.values[0][0];
  return createObject(element, objFindExcel);
});

arrValues.push(objValues);


objValues = {};
objValues.row = 1;
objValues.values = arrMap.map(function(element, index, array) {
  let objFindExcel = objFind.values[0][1];
  return createObject(element, objFindExcel);
});

arrValues.push(objValues);

console.log(arrValues);
```

Comment: Thank you Selaka, that makes sense.

I amended the code slightly as the arrMap array could change so I dont want to hardcode object properties in the createObject function